# Jquery toggle, if javascript is disabled take user to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that appears and disappears through the use of a jquery toggle. When yuo click a link the div appears or disappears.

Is there a way to make it so if javascript is disabled and a user clicks the link they are taken to a page instead?

Is there anything I should do when using a toggle to ensure it doesn't encounter problems?

Comment: Supply a *normal* href link with an A element. Then, add the appropriate `click` event with jQuery and prevent the default behavior. In this way, the jQuery event handler will only take over if JavaScript (and thus jQuery) are available; otherwise the normal href will be followed.

Comment: Or .. put the pieces together following the strategy presented. It will be fun and make for good learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the link take the user where you want them to go if js is disabled by default. Then use jQuery's `preventDefault()` on the click event (where you are probably defining your toggling behavior).

So the link should work on its own:

```
<a id="functioning-link" href="/js_disabled_page">Toggle my div</a>
```

Your jQuery should grab the click event to toggle your div, which will only work if jQuery/js is enabled:

```
$(function(){
  $("#functioning-link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please give me more detail?

Comment: I like this. Any down-falls to it?

Comment: I mean, not really. Its a pretty common approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both href and onClick for this.

If the *javascript is disabled*, **href** fires up

else **onClick**!

For example:

```
<a href="gosomewhere.html" onclick="toggle(); return false;">Click to toggle</a>
```

Javascript:

```
 toggle = function() {
     // Your code here
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are there any downfalls to this method?

Comment: @gregor: Not that I have known of! I have used it on lot of my projects.